# SCTP receive message function returning zero

Tags: sockets, sctp

The client program i have written uses SCTP sockets for communication. I am using sctp_recvmsg to read the data available for a particular user from socket. I have noticed that at times sctp_recvmsg returns 0 value instead of number of bytes read or -1 indicating an error. I have checked my code and the socket from which data is being read is not closed. Can someone throw light on how can such a behavior be seen?

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Sujay

Comment: Which OS do you use? Linux, Solaris...Could you provide code? If possible, use tcpdump/snoop to capture the network packages.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this lksctp thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/lksctp/mailman/message/21641662/), `sctp_recvmsg()` returns 0 if the other side closed the connection when you are in a 1-to-1 SCP connection ([see here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sctp.7.html) for an explanation of one-to-one and one-to-many connections) - that is, when you create the socket with `SOCK_STREAM` instead of `SOCK_SEQPACKET`.

Quoting:

> > Return values from sctp_sendmsg and sctp_recvmsg are not documented, but 
> >     I would suppose sctp_sendmsg would return -1 and set errno to ECONNRESET 
> >     same way as sendmsg does. However, what about sctp_recvnmsg? Plain 
> >     recvmsg should return 0 if half-connection is closed, but there are no 
> >     half-connections in SCTP. How does the function behave exactly?
>
> The sctp_recvmsg() will return 0 on termination only on 1-to-1 sockets.
>   However, the above notifications will work on both styles.