# What happens when sending an empty string with sctp_recvmsg() to a SOCK_STREAM SCTP socket?

Tags: sockets, sctp

As mentioned in [SCTP receive message function returning zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21595181/sctp-receive-message-function-returning-zero/31898000), `sctp_recvmsg()` returns a length of `0` for a [one-to-one](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sctp.7.html) SCTP  connection (`socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCT)`) when the other side closes the connection.

What happens / is supposed to happen for a standards compliant implementation when I send an empty string (`""`) with `sctp_sendmsg()` through such a connection?

- (How) Does the receiving side tell apart whether I closed the connection or just sent an empty string/
- Or is it illegal to send an empty string?

I haven't yet come across anything explaining this.

**EDIT:** I should mention that for standard `recv()` of `SOCK_STREAM` (e.g. for TCP), receiving a 0-length buffer happens [when the peer has performed an orderly shutdown](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv), thus [apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363496/263061) you're not allowed to `send()` an empty string in TCP. For a stream-only protocol like TCP this makes total sense, since 0-length data cannot have a meaning in a stream. But it could well have a meaning for a datagram as in the case of `sctp_recvmsg()`, so we can't really say *"it's just like for TCP"*.

Comment: In TCP an empty send is not detectable by the remote side. It is legal.

Comment: At least the linux implementation will not let you send a zero sized message, it'll fail with EINVAL. (Though you can provide an empty message  if you're shutting down/aborting a connection by the means of providing  an ancillary SCTP_SNDRCV struct in the sendmsg() call that has SCTP_EOF or SCTP_ABORT flag set)

Comment: @usr Correct. It is actually a useful way of testing the state of the connection. All the error checking happens but nothing goes on the wire or indeed into the socket send buffer.